# How to set default value on field values in a class used in spring boot request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-annotations

I am creating a GetEndpoint exposed like below

```
@GetMapping
public void someMethod(@RequestParam(value = "selectedColor", required = false, 
                          defaultValue = "WHITE") Color seletedColor) {

....

}
```

I need to convert all method parameters to a class object like below. Please let me know how to set default value **defaultValue = "WHITE"** at field level in below class

```
@GetMapping
public void someMethod(RequestParameter request) {

....

}

public Class RequestParameter {
    // How to set default value if parameter is null
    private Color seletedColor;
}
```

Comment: if you are going to make more endpoints try using Swagger (https://swagger.io/), It's really helpfull in these kind of situations

Comment: Just assign a value `private Color selectedColor = Color.WHITE`. When it isn't available in the request it will have the default value.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `getter` to have this logic. For example:

```java
public class RequestParameter {
   ...

   public Color getSelectedColor() {
      return Optional.ofNullabe(selectedColor).orElse(Color.WHITE);
   }

}
```

Comment: You generally want to avoid getters with a side-effect. Just assign a value to the field when creating the object, if not available in the requst it won't be overwritten and thus used.

Answer (score 0):

Once you decide to bind params to a custom request parameter class, you can no longer take advantage of the built-in parameter annotations that make it so easy to set defaults.

If you still want to set default values per-endpoint for one of your request class's field-level parameters, it's actually not too hard.

Make your own custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and pair it with a custom annotation that the resolver can check for.

```
public class MyRequestParameterMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    public static final String DEFAULT_COLOR = "ffffff";

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(MyRequestParameter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(
            MethodParameter parameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        String colorParam = webRequest.getParameter("color");

        // defaultColor may be overridden per-endpoint using this custom parameter annotation
        DefaultColor defaultColorAnnotation = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(DefaultColor.class);
        String defaultColor = defaultColorAnnotation != null ? defaultColorAnnotation.value() : DEFAULT_COLOR;

        Color color = Optional.ofNullable(colorParam).map(Color::decode).orElse(Color.decode(defaultColor));
        return new MyRequestParameter(color);
    }
}
```

That resolver of course must be registered

```
public class MyApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new MyRequestParameterMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
    ...
```

and then just define your custom annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;

@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface DefaultColor {
    @AliasFor("value")
    String color() default "";

    @AliasFor("color")
    String value() default "";
}
```

and finally, you will have the freedom to give each endpoint its own default color

```
@GetMapping
public void someMethod( @DefaultColor("ff0000") MyRequestParameter requestParams) {

....

}

@GetMapping
public void someOtherMethod( @DefaultColor("00ff00") MyRequestParameter requestParams) {

....

}
```